# Integrate Twitter Timeline in a LWC component for Community

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, twitter

I'm currently trying to integrate a Twitter Timeline in a LWC component to be used in Salesforce Community but the feed does not appear when my component is displayed in Community Builder and when the Community is published.

The code from Twitter Publish is the following:

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/salesforce?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by salesforce</a>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

It seems pretty straight forward but I can't add a script tag in a LWC template. So what I did is simply add

```html
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

into the Community header (Settings > Advanced > Edit Head Markup) and add platform.twitter.com in CSP Trusted Sites but it doesn't work.

Does someone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Download and add the script into a static resource and use that static resource in LWC

Comment: I just load the script in renderedCallback() using loadScript()?

Comment: I add the following to renderedCallback() `Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, twitterPlatform + '/twitterWidgets.js')
        ]).then(() => {
            console.log(twitterWidgets)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });        `


But I have the following errors `aura_proddebug.js:50208 null TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at t.exports (twitterWidgets.js:1)` and `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at t.exports (twitterWidgets.js:1)`

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I will have to check it.

Comment: I am having this exact problem, which also gives these exact errors. I have also downloaded the script and put it in a static resource. @Jean were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Did you ever manage to build this?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this by using the following component on AppExchange:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EJc1NUAT&modal=where_to_install_package